# Get logged in Windows Active Directory user remotely

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to get the currently logged in user in Windows/Active Directory to use as a Web Login. I'm wondering if this is even possible before.

Suppose you have, all on the same network

1. Client A (Chrome)
2. Server A (NodeJS on Windows)
3. Server B (LDAP on Windows)

Can Client A make an HTTP request to Server A who then makes a LDAP request to Server B to figure out which Windows Active Directory user is logged in to Client A? I have the Server A <-> Server B LDAP TCP socket working, but can I ask the LDAP server to tell me who is logged in to Client A?

This complexity is because Client A cannot probe which user is logged into Active Directory via the Browser, as far as I know.

Comment: I understand that you would like to get a user automatically logged in into a web application using credentials that the user already used for their machine logon. If so, this sounds to me like a perfect setup for Kerberos SSO.

Comment: Is it possible if the server is running Node.js?